# Adapt font and icon sizes to High Definition screen resolutions in Ubuntu-Studio XFCE

Tags: icons, fonts, xfce, display-resolution, ubuntu-studio

I have a Dell XPS 13. I got it with windows 8 and it adapts the fonts and icons to the 3200x1800 screen resolution. Then I start my virtual Ubuntu Studio 14.04 machine and they look really small. How does Ubuntu Studio handle that? Is there a way I can set it to do the same windows does (i.e. make them extra big so I can read them in menus and titles)?

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 14.04, with XFCE, so [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472262/adapt-ubuntu-to-a-high-dpi-resolution-screen) won't work because the options are different than those for Unity.

I have adapted font sizes and icons using different configuration options, and most apps seem to work, as well as Desktop.

But some applications, like Blender, won't change. Is there like a general way to tell Ubuntu-Studio "I'm using a High DPI screen, please adapt"?

Comment: Don't use a screen like that myself but if it's Unity you can change your display settings http://askubuntu.com/questions/472262/adapt-ubuntu-to-a-high-dpi-resolution-screen

Comment: That looks pretty neat for Unity, but I can't find anything like that in Xfce. :(

Comment: You might need XFCE 4.12 for better support of xhdpi display, or try a desktop enviroment. http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/a-look-at-whats-new-in-xfce-412-video.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no global setting like the zoom scale factor in Unity, but you can follow these steps to achieve most of it:

### 1. Set a Custom DPI setting

Open a terminal with CTRL+ALT+t and enter

```
    LANG=c xfce4-settings-manager
```

In "Appearence"->Fonts-> "Custom DPI Setting:" set this to 192 (instead of the default 96).

Log off and on again to accept the new settings in all windows.

### 2. Adapt Theme and settings

- Set your panel size to a height of 48
- In `xfce4-settings-manager`->"Settings Editor" (`xfce4-settings-editor`)

  - in section `xfce4-desktop` (create an entry if it doesn't exist)
    `desktop-icons/icon-size` Type Integer and set it to 128
  - in section `xsettings` set `CursorThemeSize` to 48
  - in section `xsettings` set `Gtk/IconSizes` to

    ```
    gtk-large-toolbar=32,32:gtk-small-toolbar=24,24:gtk-menu=32,32:gtk-dialog=88,88:gtk-button=32,32:gtk-dnd=32,32
    ```

    Or use the commandline:

    ```
    xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/IconSizes -s "gtk-large-toolbar=32,32:gtk-small-toolbar=24,24:gtk-menu=32,32:gtk-dialog=88,88:gtk-button=32,32:gtk-dnd=32,32"
    ```

    - `gtk-large-toolbar` are main toolbars
    - `gtk-small-toolbar` are secondary toolbars
    - `gtk-menu` are menus
    - `gtk-dialog` are dialog icons
    - `gtk-button` are buttons (eg the xfce panel uses buttons)
    - `gtk-dnd` are the icons displayed if you drag and drop a file or a folder

      you can change them to any size as long your icon theme supports it
- In `xfce4-settings-manager`->"Window Manager"

  - select the theme `Default-xhdpi` (since Xfce 4.12 - [`upgrade instructions for 14.04`](http://ubuntuportal.com/2015/03/how-to-upgrade-xfce-4-10-to-xfce-4-12-in-xubuntu-14-04-and-xubuntu-14-10.html))
  - Set the Title Font to 12
- Download the [Widepanel Appearance](http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Widepanel?content=174213)
  ** in `xfce4-settings-manager`->`"Appearance"` select `Widepanel`
- In the File Manager thunar adapt the preferences:

  - Set Iconsize in the sidepanel to "small" or "normal"

### 3. Adapt Firefox

see: [Adjust Firefox and Thunderbird to a High DPI touchscreen display (retina)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487032/adjust-firefox-and-thunderbird-to-a-high-dpi-touchscreen-display-retina)

(or use Chrome, which works fine since Version 41.0.2272.76 Ubuntu 14.10)

### 4. Increase font in Pidgin

There is a plugin you can install

```
sudo apt-get install pidgin-extprefs
```

Then you can increase the font in Plugins->Extended Prefs

### 5. Create starter for applications that still don't scale

Some applications still don't obey the global scaling (mainly java) for those few applications you can create a starter to only [Fix scaling of java-based applications for a high DPI screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526484/change-resolution-while-program-is-running)

---

*source: https://askubuntu.com/a/472266/34298*

Comment: What is the File Manager thunar?
Ah, nevermind. It's the name of an XFCE file manager. Not too familiar with XFCE myself. Thanks for the tips!